# Spring Boot with WebSocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I'm using Spring Boot with WebSocket trying to create a backend for a chat app. Everything is setup and working for Web Socket now. When I try to add user registration function, I faced a problem from server log shows

> Invalid SockJS path '/user/register' - required to have 3 path
> segments

Seems like the register call is not directed to the correct controller. Could anyone please give me some hints?

File `UserController.java`

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    //@GetMapping("/registration/{userName}")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> register(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletResponse response) {        
       // ...
    }
}
```

File `WebSocketController.java`

```java
@CrossOrigin
@Component
@RestController
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{username}", decoders = MessageDecoder.class, encoders = MessageEncoder.class)
public class WebSocketController {
    // ...
}
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to configure the servlet but not sure what to do. Could anyone enlighten me please? Thanks